# Trying to raise ArgumentError rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have an Rspec test that is not passing, and I don't understand why. All other tests are passing, except this one requiring an `ArgumentError`

The test looks like this:

```
describe "#evaluate" do
    it "raises error" do
        expect(rpn.evaluate('%')).to raise_error(ArgumentError)
    end
end
```

and my file is setup so it will raise an error (as an else statement)

```
else
  raise ArgumentError.new
end
```

but rspec is telling me this

```
Failure/Error: expect(rpn.evaluate('%')).to raise_error(ArgumentError)
     ArgumentError:
       ArgumentError
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do:

```
expect { rpn.evaluate('%') }.to raise_error(ArgumentError)
```

Ie pass a block to expect

Comment: That was it. Perfect. I'll have to read up on the difference passing a block makes.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between passing rpn.evaluate('%') as an argument and as a block is that

```
expect(rpn.evaluate('%')).to raise_error(ArgumentError)
```

will check whether the **output** of rpn.evaluate('%') raises an ArgumentError, whereas

```
expect { rpn.evaluate('%') }.to raise_error(ArgumentError)
```

will check whether **running the block of code** rpn.evaluate('%') raises an ArgumentError.