# Rails expect matcher for ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

In my RSpec model spec/models/element_type.rb I have this:

```
it "should reject duplicate names" do
  FactoryGirl.create(:element_type)
  expect(FactoryGirl.create(:element_type)).to raise_error
end
```

with the spec/factories/element_types.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :element_type do
     name "blah"
     auditor
  end
end
```

when the test runs, it fails, saying ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name has already been taken

That result is what I want - I want the test to fail because the name 
IS duplicated. ("blah") How do I match the result, using expect, that ActiveRecord is giving me?

Comment: `expect{FactoryGirl.create(:element_type)}.to raise_error` You need curly braces.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to raise ArgumentError rspec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020194/trying-to-raise-argumenterror-rspec)

Comment: @ptd, thanks very much. Why do the curly braces make a difference, versus parens here? I'd like to understand the functional difference.

Comment: @ptd, I see the other post, thanks for pointing that out. Clearly it has to do with passing a block to expect instead of an argument, but my understanding of expect is not deep yet, clearly.

Comment: The problem is that, with `( )` the code is evaluated and raises an error, so the rest of the line isn't evaluated. The `{ }` block sort of sandboxes it so the error raised doesn't stop the rest of the evaluation.

Comment: @ptd please add your comment as an answer to get this marked as answered